# test a pop3 secure ssl port 995

Tags: windows, exchange, pop3

i am trying to login to microsoft exchange online using openssl

```
openssl s_client -connect pop.mail.apac.microsoftonline.com:995
```

however when i pass the USER command it fails

```
+OK The Microsoft Exchange POP3 service is ready.
user myusername@fomain.com
-ERR Connection is closed. 12
read:errno=0
```

any ideas on how to test this?

**more research**

i tried

```
nc -v pop.mail.microsoftonline.com 995
Connection to pop.mail.microsoftonline.com 995 port [tcp/pop3s] succeeded!

user user@fomain.com
```

but no results...

**fixed**

```
openssl s_client -crlf -connect pop.mail.apac.microsoftonline.com:995
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You have to actually follow the [POP3 protocol](http://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc1939.txt):

> Commands ... consist of a case-insensitive keyword, possibly
>      followed by one or more arguments.  **All commands are terminated by a
>      CRLF pair**.  Keywords and arguments consist of printable ASCII
>      characters.  Keywords and arguments are each separated by a single
>      SPACE character.  Keywords are three or four characters long. Each
>      argument may be up to 40 characters long.

Try passing `-crlf` to `s_client`.